# Image for ImageButton doesn't change as intended

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

My goal here is to change an Image from an ImageButton(ibChamp).

```
package com.example.custombuilds;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;z
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Champions extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.champions);

    ImageButton ibAnnie = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibAnnie);

    ibAnnie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Check this for errors
            RelativeLayout test = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutChampions);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_build_page, null);
            test.addView(view);
            ImageButton img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibChamp);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            try {
                Intent open = new Intent("android.intent.action.CREATE");
                startActivity(open);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Note that the ImageButton ibChamp is from the xml layout create_build_page, and not the xml champions.
This code runs without crashing, but the Image from the Imagebutton ibChamp does not change, which is what I am trying to do. I will be happy to provide any other additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating "ibChamp" in onClick. That creates a new ImageButton. You will not see it until you use "addView" from the parent.

You can add your XML, but you need to get a reference to an existing button in Activity in order to change it. Or else add the new button and remove an old one...

In other words, change this:

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_build_page, null);
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibChamp);
```

to this:

```
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibChamp);
```

And it will probably do what you want.

Comment: I already have a ImageButton in the xml, and I tried removing all that and doing as you said, but it causes a null pointer exception and crashes the program, so that's why I'm doing it this way

Comment: yes - because your activity is calling this:  setContentView(R.layout.champions); but ibChamp ImageButton is not in that layout. It is in "create_build_page" - why do you have two different layouts? If you are trying to add it dynamically, then call findViewById((R.layout.champions) and do the addView to that object.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call addView() for this inflated view

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_build_page, null);
```

Comment: How would I call addView()?

Comment: If you can post R.layout.champions xml file and R.layout.create_build_page xml file, we can recommend appropriate solution. Anyway you can add LinearLayout with id let say "parent" in your champion.xml. then `LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
 parent.addView(view)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added your code into the post. Although it doesn't crash, it doesn't work as I would intend it to be. What happens now after I click the ImageButton "ibAnnie" is that it would seem to change ibChamp successfully and open up create_build_page.xml fine, but then it pops up create_build_page.xml without the change in the picture. Then if I click ibChamp again, the cycle continues. Any suggestions for a solution?