# ImageButton changing an Image of another ImageButton causes unintended cycle

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

Aftermath of this: [Image for ImageButton doesn't change as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592015/image-for-imagebutton-doesnt-change-as-intended)

When ImageButton of "ibChamp" is clicked, it opens up champions.xml. In that layout, there is an Imagebutton called "ibAnnie". What I want that to do when clicked is, to change the image of "ibChamp", and to switch to that layout. What happened here is that after "ibAnnie" is clicked, it switches to "create_build_page.xml", and in that is a changed picture of "ibChamp". But that only happens for a split second before changing back to the original, unchanged picture, "create_build_page.xml" layout. When I click the back button, it goes to the "create_build_page.xml" layout with the changed picture, but the buttons do not work. I would gladly provide any additional information required.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code to clarify?

Comment: There's some confusing stuff going on there... you inflate an xml layout and add it to your current Activity's layout and then you start an Activity, which presumably has its own layout and everything... is that your intention?

Comment: That is my intention yes

Comment: If this is confusing, I can further explain the situation

Comment: Why do you edit your layout and then open another Activity? What Activity does that call open?

Comment: The layout that I edited is the same layout that I open so I can see the changes

Comment: An Activity is not a layout. The layout that you edit is in one Activity, then when you start an Activity that creates a whole other layout. Are you opening the same Activity as you already have open? Then this is what is happening: You have an ActivityA displaying LayoutA. You add LayoutB to it, and then open a new copy of ActivityA, which displays a completely different copy of LayoutA.

Comment: My goal is when ImageButtonA is clicked, it opens a new layout where I can select from a list of other ImageButtons, so that ImageButtonA takes on the Image that I chosen from the list. When I click one Image from the list, I want ImageButtonA to display that picture that I chose.

Comment: Actually I solved the cycle of layouts being opened just now, but now even if the image is changed, the buttons don't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve... but if my understanding is correct, this should get you closer:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.champions);

    ImageButton ibAnnie = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibAnnie);

    ibAnnie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            RelativeLayout test = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutChampions);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View createView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_build_page, null);
            test.addView(createView);

            ImageButton img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibChamp);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            img.setTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // so you can retrieve it later
            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // this will set the imageView of ibAnnie
                    ibAnnie.setImageView((Integer)view.getTag());
                    // this will remove the selection view from your layout
                    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutChampions)).removeChild(createView);
                }
            });

            // this opens another Activity... you don't want that, at least not for what you seem to be trying to do.
            /*try {
                Intent open = new Intent("android.intent.action.CREATE");
                startActivity(open);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }*/

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I will test this soon, many thanks for the constant support and help

Comment: It says that "The method removeChild(View) is undefined for the type RelativeLayout"

Comment: Check the documentation, I may have the wrong function name.

Comment: The problem has been solved by a bit of tinkering with your code, thanks!